# Emitting images using socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Rather than just sending text alone with **Socket.io**, i'm trying to add images as well. The idea is to allow users to add images to their post that would normally just contain text. (The code in isolation is given at the end. The layout of the photos change depending on the number of images uploaded.)

**What should happen**

After choosing the images you want, a preview is displayed. After your type a message and press enter, the message and the images should be emitted and a post should be created.

**What is happening**

The code works in isolation. But when I try to integrate it with sockets.io I get the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

**What I tried**

**Required code in the Server**

```
clientSocket.on('post', function(data) {
  io.sockets.emit('post', data);
});
```

**Front end code**

```js
let control = document.getElementById("file-upload");
let inputFields = document.querySelector(".input-fields");
let container = document.querySelector(".post-container");
let postInput = document.querySelector(".post-input");

/* Provide the preview */
control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  // When the control has changed, there are new files

  files = control.files,
    len = files.length;


  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!files[i].type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {

      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = event.target.result;
      img.setAttribute("class", "thumbnail");
      inputFields.appendChild(img);
    };

    reader.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  }


});


/* emit the files uploaded using the file API */

postInput.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if ((event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) && postInput.value != "") {
    socket.emit('post', {
      message: postInput.value,
      files: files
    });
    postInput.value = "";
  }
});


/* Create the post */
socket.on('post', function(data) {

  let files = data.files;

  // Ensure only four images gets displayed.
  len = (data.files.length > 4) ? 4 : data.files.length;


  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!files[i].type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {

      let node = document.createTextNode(data.message);
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.appendChild(node);
      conatiner.appendChild(div);

      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = event.target.result;
      img.setAttribute("class", `layout-${len}-image-${i+1}`);
      container.appendChild(img);
    };

    reader.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  }

  if (files.length > 4) {
    let node = document.createTextNode("+ " + (data.files.length - 4));
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "text");
    div.appendChild(node);
    container.appendChild(div);
  }
});
```

```css
.input-fields>img {
  /* display:flex; */
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.grid-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  padding: 4px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: 100;
  z-index: 2;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* First Layout */

.layout-1-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}


/* Second Layout */

.layout-2-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.layout-2-image-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}


/* Third Layout */

.layout-3-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.layout-3-image-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.layout-3-image-3 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}


/* Forth Layout */

.layout-4-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.layout-4-image-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.layout-4-image-3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

.layout-4-image-4 {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<input class="post-input" type="text"  placeholder="Write something...">
<input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple>
<div class="input-fields"></div>
<section class="post-container"></section>
```

**The code in isolation.**

```js
let control = document.getElementById("file-upload");
let container = document.querySelector(".grid-container");

control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  // When the control has changed, there are new files

  files = control.files,

    // Ensure only four images gets displayed.
    len = (files.length > 4) ? 4 : files.length;


  // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    // Only process image files.
    if (!files[i].type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {

      let img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = event.target.result;
      img.setAttribute("class", `layout-${len}-image-${i+1}`);
      container.appendChild(img);
    };

    reader.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code);
    };
    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
  }
  
  if (files.length > 4) {
    let node = document.createTextNode((files.length - 4) + " +");
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "text");
    div.appendChild(node);
    container.appendChild(div);
  }

});
```

```css
.grid-container{
  position:relative;
  width: 400px;
  height:400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto;
  padding: 4px;
}

.text{
  position:absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  color:white;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: lightest;
  z-index: 2;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
/* First Layout */
.layout-1-image-1{
  grid-column: 1 / 5;
  grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

/* Second Layout */
.layout-2-image-1{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}
.layout-2-image-2{
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

/* Third Layout */
.layout-3-image-1{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}
.layout-3-image-2{
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.layout-3-image-3{
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 3 / 5;
}

/* Forth Layout */
.layout-4-image-1{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.layout-4-image-2{
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
.layout-4-image-3{
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
.layout-4-image-4{
    grid-column: 3 / 5;
    grid-row: 3 / 5;
}
```

```html
<input id="file-upload" type="file" multiple>
<section class="grid-container"></section>
```

Comment: Have you tried using "readAsArrayBuffer" instead of "readAsDataUrl":  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(files[i]);

Comment: I have but I get the  same error.

Comment: I didn't know how we can send images using buffer in socket.io, pls. let me know if you find the solution.  Instead, I always transform the images to/from base64 String before send/receive, and it works pretty well except that I think this work around is slower.

Comment: @ Kenneth Li Unfortunately I never did figure  this out.